# Could not resolve host when trying to access service in gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to access a gitlab-service from a container started with `docker run`, but it doesn't seem to work.

They actually have a nice section on gitlab about this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#using-services-with-docker-run-docker-in-docker-side-by-side

However, even after a 1:1 copy of their code:

```yaml
access-service:
  stage: build
  image: docker:19.03.1
  before_script:
    - echo "Overriding default before_script"
  services:
    - docker:dind # necessary for docker run
    - tutum/wordpress:latest
  variables:
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true" # activate container-to-container networking
  script: |
    docker run --rm --name curl \
      --volume  "$(pwd)":"$(pwd)"    \
      --workdir "$(pwd)"             \
      --network=host                 \
      curlimages/curl:7.74.0 curl "http://tutum-wordpress"
```

I get an error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.3.4 (77516d85)
  on gitlab-aws-autoscaler 7ee750d2
  feature flags: FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD:true, FF_DISABLE_UMASK_FOR_DOCKER_EXECUTOR:true
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor 02:34
Using Docker executor with image docker:19.03.1 ...
WARNING: Container based cache volumes creation is disabled. Will not create volume for "/cache"
Starting service docker:dind ...
Authenticating with credentials from $DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image sha256:1a42336ff683d7dadd320ea6fe9d93a5b101474346302d23f96c9b4546cb414d for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:6f2ae4a5fd85ccf85cdd829057a34ace894d25d544e5e4d9f2e7109297fedf8d ...
Starting service tutum/wordpress:latest ...
Authenticating with credentials from $DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG
Pulling docker image tutum/wordpress:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:7e7f97a602ff0c3a30afaaac1e681c72003b4c8a76f8a90696f03e785bf36b90 for tutum/wordpress:latest with digest tutum/wordpress@sha256:2aa05fd3e8543b615fc07a628da066b48e6bf41cceeeb8f4b81e189de6eeda77 ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
*** WARNING: Service runner-7ee750d2-project-2-concurrent-0-483783518ce3e922-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
service "runner-7ee750d2-project-2-concurrent-0-483783518ce3e922-docker-0-wait-for-service" timeout
Health check container logs:
Service container logs:
2022-02-22T20:44:10.523612305Z Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
2022-02-22T20:44:11.037778878Z ...................................................................................++++
2022-02-22T20:44:11.319540033Z ..................................++++
2022-02-22T20:44:11.320611978Z e is 65537 (0x010001)
2022-02-22T20:44:11.341349948Z Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
2022-02-22T20:44:11.360835661Z .++++
2022-02-22T20:44:11.678902603Z ...................................................++++
2022-02-22T20:44:11.679451336Z e is 65537 (0x010001)
2022-02-22T20:44:11.719133216Z Signature ok
2022-02-22T20:44:11.719148571Z subject=CN = docker:dind server
2022-02-22T20:44:11.719151811Z Getting CA Private Key
2022-02-22T20:44:11.734914635Z /certs/server/cert.pem: OK
2022-02-22T20:44:11.738748856Z Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
2022-02-22T20:44:11.993700065Z .........................................++++
2022-02-22T20:44:12.036121070Z .....++++
2022-02-22T20:44:12.036364885Z e is 65537 (0x010001)
2022-02-22T20:44:12.067743203Z Signature ok
2022-02-22T20:44:12.067755273Z subject=CN = docker:dind client
2022-02-22T20:44:12.067758449Z Getting CA Private Key
2022-02-22T20:44:12.081823033Z /certs/client/cert.pem: OK
2022-02-22T20:44:12.174949567Z time="2022-02-22T20:44:12.174783104Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
2022-02-22T20:44:12.177055953Z time="2022-02-22T20:44:12.176931675Z" level=warning msg="could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found"
2022-02-22T20:44:12.177086275Z failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: device or resource busy
*********
Authenticating with credentials from $DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG
Pulling docker image docker:19.03.1 ...
Using docker image sha256:0cecfefe921f22fc898f7a0055358380c8870ab6f05b01999367911714fe9d00 for docker:19.03.1 with digest docker@sha256:2dcf87c9893b05ab815880e3d223cd6976c388a6f6697de10e90523255259ca4 ...
Not using umask - FF_DISABLE_UMASK_FOR_DOCKER_EXECUTOR is set!

...

$ docker run --rm --name curl \ # collapsed multi-line command
Unable to find image 'curlimages/curl:7.74.0' locally
7.74.0: Pulling from curlimages/curl
aad63a933944: Pulling fs layer

...

3d4876cbff99: Pull complete
110e7f874674: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:a3e534fced74aeea171c4b59082f265d66914d09a71062739e5c871ed108a46e
Status: Downloaded newer image for curlimages/curl:7.74.0
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: tutum-wordpress
```

Can anyone give me a pointer why this is not working? Does this have to do with the fact that this is the executer `docker+machine` and not `docker`?

Here's our config.toml:

```ini
[[runners]]
  name = "gitlab-aws-autoscaler"
  url = "https://code.example.com"
  token = "${TOKEN}"
  executor = "docker+machine"
  limit = ${LIMIT_MEDIUM_RUNNERS}
  [runners.docker]
    image = "example/gitlabrunner:2.10"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = true
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache", "/builds:/builds"]
    wait_for_services_timeout = 120
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    ServerAddress = "s3.amazonaws.com"
    AccessKey = "${KEY}"
    SecretKey = "${SECRET}"
    BucketName = "example-gitlab-runner-cache-virginia"
    BucketLocation = "us-east-1"
    Shared = true
  [runners.machine]
    IdleCount = 0
    IdleTime = 1800
    MaxBuilds = 100
    MachineDriver = "amazonec2"
    MachineName = "gitlab-docker-machine-%s"
    MachineOptions = [
      "amazonec2-instance-type=t2.medium",
      "amazonec2-access-key=${KEY}",
      "amazonec2-secret-key=${SECRET}",
      "amazonec2-root-size=100", # GB
      "amazonec2-region=us-east-1",
      "amazonec2-tags=runner-manager-name,gitlab-aws-autoscaler,gitlab,true,gitlab-runner-autoscale,true",
      "amazonec2-security-group=EC2-X-ci-runner",
      "amazonec2-vpc-id=vpc-XXX",
      "amazonec2-subnet-id=subnet-XXX",
      "amazonec2-zone=b",
      "amazonec2-use-private-address=true",
      "amazonec2-private-address-only=true"
    ]
```

**Edit:**

When trying to set the `DOCKER_HOST` variable as suggested in one answer, I get the following errors:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.3.4 (77516d85)
  on gitlab-aws-autoscaler 7ee750d2
  feature flags: FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD:true, FF_DISABLE_UMASK_FOR_DOCKER_EXECUTOR:true
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor 02:42
Using Docker executor with image docker:19.03.1 ...
WARNING: Container based cache volumes creation is disabled. Will not create volume for "/cache"
Starting service docker:dind ...
Authenticating with credentials from $DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image sha256:1a42336ff683d7dadd320ea6fe9d93a5b101474346302d23f96c9b4546cb414d for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:6f2ae4a5fd85ccf85cdd829057a34ace894d25d544e5e4d9f2e7109297fedf8d ...
Starting service tutum/wordpress:latest ...
Authenticating with credentials from $DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG
Pulling docker image tutum/wordpress:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:7e7f97a602ff0c3a30afaaac1e681c72003b4c8a76f8a90696f03e785bf36b90 for tutum/wordpress:latest with digest tutum/wordpress@sha256:2aa05fd3e8543b615fc07a628da066b48e6bf41cceeeb8f4b81e189de6eeda77 ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
*** WARNING: Service runner-7ee750d2-project-2-concurrent-0-a0ec4dc562ad3891-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
service "runner-7ee750d2-project-2-concurrent-0-a0ec4dc562ad3891-docker-0-wait-for-service" timeout
Health check container logs:
Service container logs:
2022-02-24T16:21:42.803216350Z time="2022-02-24T16:21:42.803077740Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
2022-02-24T16:21:42.804161387Z time="2022-02-24T16:21:42.804107933Z" level=warning msg="could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found"
2022-02-24T16:21:42.804233443Z failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: device or resource busy
*********
Authenticating with credentials from $DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG
Pulling docker image docker:19.03.1 ...
Using docker image sha256:0cecfefe921f22fc898f7a0055358380c8870ab6f05b01999367911714fe9d00 for docker:19.03.1 with digest docker@sha256:2dcf87c9893b05ab815880e3d223cd6976c388a6f6697de10e90523255259ca4 ...
```

Comment: The difference between `docker` and `docker+machine` should not be significant here. For example, this job configuration works on `gitlab.com` runners, which use `docker+machine`. It also works on my self-hosted runner using the `docker` executor. However, it may depend on how your self-hosted runner is configured to enable docker/dind. Could you edit your question to include the sanitized gitlab-runner TOML configuration file?

Comment: @sytech i added the config toml

Comment: I see the reason why this is not working. In short, the reason is because of the docker socket bind-mount. Your job is using the host daemon socket, not the `docker:dind` service container. Can you try setting the following variables in your job: `DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"` and `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""` and see if that fixes your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your job is not utilizing the `docker:dind` service. While you have your job configured mostly correct, your docker GitLab runner defines the following volumes configuration:

```
volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache", "/builds:/builds"]
```

When bind-mounting `/var/run/docker.sock`, and not providing the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable, your jobs will default to using the bind-mounted docker socket and connect to the daemon on the "metal" host directly, instead of connecting to the `docker:dind` container, which is required for this `services:` setup to work correctly.

You can run `docker info` in your job to confirm this.

You should be able to fix this by setting the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable in your job (normally, this is set for you when using `gitlab.com` runners, which is why it is omitted in their documentation).

```yaml
access-service:
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  # ...
```

---

Note: `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR` is also unset here to disable TLS to ensure port 2375 is used. Using TLS is an available option and should be considered more secure.

Comment: I tried this, now I get a different error: `$ docker run --rm --name curl \ # collapsed multi-line command
docker: error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.40/containers/create?name=curl: dial tcp: lookup docker on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host.`

Comment: @bersling that's interesting. The `docker:dind` container defined in `services:` should be available at the hostname `docker`. I would wonder (1) if you may be using a name for the container other than `docker:dind` (like if using a different registry) or (2) if the dind container is somehow failing. Unfortunately, service failures are hard to debug, but double check the job log output to see if the dind service container is failing. If you're using an alternative image registry to pull the docker:dind image, you must add an explicit alias in the `services:` configuration.

Comment: You might also get better luck using `docker:latest` for the job image or using an explicit matching version for the dind service image, like `docker:19.03.12-dind` -- for my own self-hosted runners, we do not provide the bind mount at all. Removing the docker socket mount may also help -- but it will also mean that you must always use the dind service any time you want to use `docker` (which you normally don't have to do if you bind mount the socket).

Comment: you are right, there seems to be an error when starting. something about the docker group. And I think not binding to docker socket mount might be cleaner and just using the dind service when wanting to access docker. We might consider that!